# Reverse Audio in JavaScript/Angular

Tags: javascript, audio, buffer, html5-audio, web-audio-api

I want to implement an audio player's rewind functionality so than I hear the audio playing in fast rewind while I'm holding the rewind button down.

I have an `AudioBuffer` and I am reversing it, but when playing it, I can't hear anything. However, the fast forward mode I implemented does work fine:

```
private gainNode: GainNode = {} as GainNode;
private aCtx = new AudioContext({ sampleRate: 16000 });
private source?: AudioBufferSourceNode;

// [...]

if (this.source) {
  this.source = this.aCtx.createBufferSource();

  let bufferToPlay = this.speechAudioBufferService.getModifyedBuffer;

  if (this.speechAudioBufferService.getModifyedBuffer && this.fastRewind) {
    const actualBuffer = this.speechAudioBufferService.getModifyedBuffer;
    const channels = actualBuffer.numberOfChannels;
    const length = actualBuffer.length;
    const reversedBuffer = this.aCtx.createBuffer(channels, length, actualBuffer.sampleRate);

    for (let channel = 0; channel < channels; channel++) {
      const originalData = actualBuffer.getChannelData(channel);
      const reversedData = reversedBuffer.getChannelData(channel);

      for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
        reversedData[i] = originalData[length - i - 1];
      }
    }

    bufferToPlay?.copyFromChannel(reversedBuffer.getChannelData(0), 0);
  }

  if (bufferToPlay) {
    this.source.buffer = bufferToPlay;
  }

  this.source.playbackRate.value = this.playRate();

  this.source
    .connect(this.gainNode)
    .connect(this.aCtx.destination);

  this.source.start(0, this.positionAndDurationService.currentPosition);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is incorrect, as you fill in `reversedData` but never put that data back into `reversedBuffer`:

```
const originalData = actualBuffer.getChannelData(channel);
const reversedData = reversedBuffer.getChannelData(channel);

for (let i = 0; i < length; i++) {
  reversedData[i] = originalData[length - i - 1];
}
```

Where does `reversedData` go now? Nowhere. So, when you run:

```
bufferToPlay?.copyFromChannel(reversedBuffer.getChannelData(0), 0);
```

You are just copying one channel from an empty buffer (`reversedBuffer`) into `bufferToPlay`.

Here's a simpler way to do it, copying all channels and using [`Float32Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Float32Array) and its [`.revese()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/TypedArray/reverse) method:

```
if (this.speechAudioBufferService.getModifyedBuffer && this.fastRewind) {
  const {
    numberOfChannels,
    length,
    sampleRate,
  } = bufferToPlay.numberOfChannels;

  const reversedBuffer = this.aCtx.createBuffer(
    numberOfChannels,
    length,
    sampleRate,
  );

  for (let channel = 0; channel < numberOfChannels; ++channel) {
    const reversedSamples = bufferToPlay.getChannelData(channel).reverse();

    reversedBuffer.copyToChannel(reversedSamples, channel);
  }

  bufferToPlay = reversedBuffer;
}
```